# How to set up a hierarchy in a XSD specification?

Tags: xsd

i am new in the field of xsd specification and i need the help from the stackoverflow community. What i want to do is to define a category hierarchy.

Example:

1. Category A 
   1.1. Category B 
       1.1.1 Category C

How can i define this in a xsd specification?
Maybe there are some best practice solutions for this.

Chris

I have tried to specify it like this way. But i am not sure if it is a practicable approach.

```
<xs:element name="category">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="maincategory">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="subcategory">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element ref="subcategory"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="maincategory" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="subcategory" type="xs:string"/>
```

Chris

Comment: I have added what i have tried above in the question

Comment: Does it work as is?  Do you want help fixing it, or do you want to make it cleaner?

Comment: I would like to make it cleaner. It works but i am not happy with that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two things named "subcategory".  I've renamed the element to "element".

This is what I would do:

```
<xs:complexType name="category_t">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="maincategory" type="main_category_t" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="main_category_t">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element type="subcategory_t" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="subcategory_t">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="element" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="category" type="category_t" />
```

I think you probably don't need to use the `ref` attribute.  That has a very specific use case, and the `type` attribute appears closer to what you want.

Comment: Hello Robert! Sorry for the late answer. But this is what i am was looking for. Thank you for your help.